# Getting wrong answer when using the elimination method to find values a and b that make f(x) continuous

Tags: limits, continuity

We have

$$
   f(x) = 
     \begin{cases}
       \dfrac{x^2-9}{x-3}, & x<3\\[6pt]
       ax^2+bx+21, & 3\leq x <4\\[6pt]
       x-7, & x\geq 4
     \end{cases}
$$

We know that 
$$
\lim_{x \to 3^+}f(x) = 9a+3b+21\\
\lim_{x \to 3^-} f(x) = 6\\
\lim_{x \to 4^+} f(x) = -3\\
\lim_{x \to 4^-} f(x) = 16a+4b+21
$$

This gives us the two equations:
$$
9a+3b+21=6\\
16a+4b+21=-3
$$
Solving this system by substitution I get the right answer of $b=-2,a=-1$

But, when I solve through elimination like so I get $a=-2,b=1$ and with these the function is only continuous at $x=3$.
$$
[9a+3b+21=6] \cdot \frac{-1}{3} \to -3a-b-6=-2\\
[16a+4b+21=-3] \cdot \frac{1}{4} \to 4a+b+\frac{21}{4} = \frac{-3}{4}
$$
Combining these two I get:
$$
4a-3a+b-b+\frac{21}{4} -6 = \frac{-3}{4} -2
$$
And solving for a I get $a=-2$. Perhaps I am making some sort of mistake in my use of elimination or is there some other reason for why I get this answer?

Comment: $21\cdot \frac{-1}{3} = -7$

Comment: Oh, wow. I can't believe I didn't spot that. Thanks!

Comment: That's the sort of mistake one almost never spots after one made it, one needs a pair of fresh eyes.